# VBA Find - I would like to create a macro to find a value from another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to add the code "If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then", How can I do it? Here below there is the code that is working only when finds something!

```
Sub ORDER()

    Dim wordToSearch As String
    Dim rowToDelete As Integer

Sheets("Dashboard").Select
RowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "W").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To RowCount

Range("W" & i).Select
check_value = ActiveCell
If check_value = "Y" Or check_value = "y" Then



    Sheets("Dashboard").Select
    wordToSearch = Sheets("Dashboard").Range("L" & i).Value

    Sheets("Order").Select
    Cells.Find(What:=wordToSearch, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    rowToDelete = ActiveCell.Row
    Rows(rowToDelete & ":" & rowToDelete).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Sheets("Dashboard").Select
    End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  I see you're starting out with VBA.  It's a great beginner language to learn, especially because of the countless tutorials and other resources, only a Google Search away.  Stack Overflow is a great place to find ask & answer questions that can't be found anywhere else.  It's not really a good place to find a crash course.  I see you've mixed up a few different commands (plus your question isn't formatted so it's tough to troubleshoot,)  Check out the tour [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and then there are some great tips here: [ask]

Comment: What is your specific question?

Answer (score 0):

The better (and safer) way to use `Find` is to `Set a Range` to the result of the `Find`, and in case `Find` failed to "find" a match, then the result will be `Range = Nothing`, and you can try to trap this type of error by using `If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then`.

**Code**

```
Sub Macro()

Dim FindRng As Range

With Sheets("order")
    Set FindRng = .Cells.Find(What:=Sheets("Dashboard").Cells(2, 4), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

    If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then ' find was successful
        FindRng.EntireRow.Delete
    Else ' Find failed to find a match
        MsgBox "Unable to find " & Sheets("Dashboard").Cells(2, 4), vbCritical
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @AntoninoConforto what do you mean problems ? are you getting a run-time error on this line ? can you specify a litle ?

Comment: may you have a look again at my code? I edited my post and now I would like to know where I should add the line "FindRng is Nothing then..."